# EF inMemory provider falsely accepting null entries when the fields are set to required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing

Here is my integration test code:

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Should only add AssetType when Name Provided")]
public async Task Test4()
{
    using (var context = GetContext()) {

        var listAssetTypes = await context.AssetType.ToListAsync();

        Assert.Equal(0, listAssetTypes.Count);

        var goodAssetType = new AssetType { Name = "1st Item" };
        context.Add(goodAssetType);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        listAssetTypes = await context.AssetType.ToListAsync();

        Assert.Equal(1, listAssetTypes.Count);

        var badAssetType = new AssetType {};
        context.Add(badAssetType);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        listAssetTypes = await context.AssetType.ToListAsync();

        Assert.Equal(1, listAssetTypes.Count);
    }
}
```

The first two assert's pass. The 3rd fails, Actual is 2, and if I debug I can see a new Id has been assigned and the name is set to null.

Here is my context method:

```
private WorldContext GetContext()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    var config = builder.Build();
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WorldContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;
    var context = new WorldContext(config, options);
    return context;
}
```

And my model:

```
public class AssetType
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(databaseGeneratedOption: DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int AssetTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First, this is *not* a unit test. It's an integration test. Second, you're testing the framework, not your application's code. In other words, just throw this test away entirely. It's not even worth trying to figure out what's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that the InMemory provider is not a production ready relational database provider and was only provided to assist with integration tests.

It won't (necessarly) enforce the consistency of your data or ensure that the constrains are fulfilled like a real database provider would do.

This is clearly documented and expected behavior, please read the documentation "[Test with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#inmemory-is-not-a-relational-database)"

> ### InMemory is not a relational database
>
> EF Core database providers do
> not have to be relational databases. InMemory is designed to be a
> general purpose database for testing, and is not designed to mimic a
> relational database.
>
> Some examples of this include:
>
> - InMemory will allow you to save data that would violate referential integrity
>   constraints in a relational database.
> - If you use DefaultValueSql(string) for a property in your model, this is a
>   relational database API and will have no effect when running against
>   InMemory. Tip
>
> For many test purposes these difference will not matter. However, if
> you want to test against something that behaves more like a true
> relational database, then consider using SQLite in-memory mode.

That being said: If you really need to validate the constraints, follow the documentation's recommendation and use Sqlite in memory database instead for your integration tests.

Comment: I wouldn't even use SQLite if that's not the production database. Each query provider is different.

Comment: Much appreciated. I've been asked to write a unit test to ensure it's impossible to submit incomplete data. I googled unit testing with EF and mocking EF and I came across numerous suggestions of using InMemory, hailed as a new convenience to avoid having to mock. Are you saying there's no such thing as unit testing a database?

Comment: Well, EF Core/its providers are separate library, so you can't nor shouldn't unit test them. Integration tests however are different, since integration tests involve more than one component/code block to test. Unit test only test a limited functionality, often a single method call **without any dependencies**. However EF Core is an external dependency, so you can do integration tests on it. Or you abstract EF core away from your business logic (i.e. using repositories or CQRS pattern)

Comment: Of course you can also use the real provider (SqlServer or whatever your production database ist) for integration tests, but then you are mainly testing your database schema/EF Core configuration rather than its consistency. There are different other approaches  (such as domain driven design) which will validate the models before they are sent to the database. You shouldn't really ever trust a provider/database to enforce your business rules.

Comment: @egmfrs: Your test should center around the controller having `ModelState` with errors, given an invalid post. The database doesn't even need to come into play. Then, you can also test to ensure that the view is returned in that scenario instead of the redirect that would occur on a successful post. Both of those, too, are integration tests, not unit tests.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for a much more helpful comment than your previous. This is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @Chris that is, assuming they use their entities as viewmodels, which they generally shouldn't. In that case you'd have to repeat the annotations, or use a shared metadata class to have comparable validation between viewmodels and entities.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Not at all. If the requirement is that a field must be required in a post, then that is something that should be validated on the view model, not the entity, anyways. Having `Required` on the entity is only to enforce NOT NULL at the database level, which honesty is inconsequential if the user input is validated first. In any case, it's still a separate requirement.

Comment: @Chris I see it as that they want to test whether the appropriate fields on their entities have a `[Required]` attribute. That ideally doesn't touch viewmodels or controllers.

Comment: Well I suppose you could use reflection to write a test that would verify that the property has that attribute, but that seems like a very strange unit test to me. Generally, with testing, you want to ensure behavior, not any one particular implementation of that behavior. While it requires an integration test, ensuring that `ModelState` has errors is the best and most accurate way to test that the desired behavior is present.